# Eclipse java debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have problem with code e.g.:

```
Object1.method1(object2.method2(var2));
```

I want to enter in method1 but when I press F5 in Eclipse - me transfer to method2.
Is possible in Eclipse debugger point that need enter only in method1? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

either:

1) place a breakpoint in method1, *resume* (`F8`) and let the code break at the breakpoint you've set.

or

2) while being at method2, *step return* (`F7`) and then again *step into* (`F5`) will place you in method1.

Comment: +1 but it would have been a good feature to be able to go to method1 in the first time... particularly when you are chaining a lot of methods

Comment: @Sebastien. Then do not build Russian dolls from the method calls.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is doing exactly the right thing. In order to execute method1, it first needs to compute the return value of method2 (which is the parameter to be passed to method1).